# Are tattoos "banned" or seen as bad at your company?

Tags: company-policy, appearance

I work at an IT company.

I have some tattoos, on my arms and body. It isn't a problem right now.

I now want to make a new little tattoo behind my neck. I wish to know other company's policies to know if I will have problems in the future in other companies, and your opinion of course.

Comment: Any answer would be company specific, it all depends on the company.

Comment: Base it off the companies dress code policy, if you don't have to wear a suit you're probably fine. At the end of the day though, probably best to ask your manager. That's what I did before dying my hair pink. I doubt any IT company would have an issue though, especially if you're not client facing. (UK btw)

Comment: Also depends on the tattoo, offensive, antisocial or gang related tattoos can be an issue. Tattoo placement is another issue... Polynesians tend to have a lot of tattoos yet some countries frown upon facial ones, others don't. Depends on their tattoo traditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while specific policies vary from company to company, most have policies about VISIBLE tattoos, and how and if they must be covered.

Speak directly to HR and ask them before doing anything.  Beyond that, it varies wildly from company to company, and industry to industry.

Also, look at what management is sporting.  If the CEO has a massive face-tattoo, then it likely wouldn't be a problem.  If no tattoos are to be seen anywhere, that's a problem.  The business world is all about being a "good fit".  If you're going to stand out in a way that  is not accepted by the company, you will not have a future.

again, see HR.

Comment: "*If the CEO has a massive face-tattoo, then it wouldn't be a problem.*" -> I remember reading a bio of Walt Disney saying that, for decades, no one (working for his company) *but* him could wear a moustache. And a quick search [brought this up](https://www.nytimes.com/2000/03/27/us/national-news-briefs-mustache-ban-lifted-for-disney-employees.html). Better be careful then ;)

Comment: I like the answer, except for the part about speaking with HR.  HR has to give a legalistic response that's safe for PR.  They might inwardly know you'd be a terrible fit for whatever reason, but not want to actually say so.

Comment: @OldPadawan You got to read that article correctly before making a broad comment such as that. The key words are PARK EMPLOYEES which means people who greet customers and take care of kids. It makes sense they would have grooming standards as they wouldn't want Peter Pan, or Cinderella to have full blown beards burning a permanent bad impression on kids who might not be expecting that. I'm sure 9-5 officer workers can grow moustaches and beards willy nilly as I recall watching disney films and animators with moustaches.

Comment: @Kevin If he clears it with HR before doing anything, he's good.

Comment: @dan : I gave an example with a tiny bit of proof, but from what I remember reading : it was "**no one**". Litterally.

Answer (score 1):

We all know what the theoretical answer is: it shouldn't matter.

The problem is, you're going up against a mental connection in a lot of people's minds:

> **person with tattoo = person that's dangerous.**

I'm not saying that's right, or even something with an actual correlation.  But it's definitely an association that exists for a sizable number of people.  And... it's not something completely benign, either.  A sense of danger is not something that's easily dismissed by mental effort.

I'm not saying "Don't get the tattoo".  But you should definitely take that factor into consideration, and weigh the costs and risks of it.  I personally wouldn't, but that's because the tattoo wouldn't give me much "benefit" - and the risks would greatly outweigh it.  But you wouldn't place the same value as me - so ultimately, it'll be up to you to decide whether to get it.

Comment: It's definitely an aging philosophy, but certainly one that still exists. But this can vary between company cultures. You probably won't experience an issue in most strictly tech companies, the Googles and Google-inspired company cultures of the world. But a tech position in a non-tech company, most likely frowned upon there.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to know other company's policies to know if I will have problems in the future in other companies, and your opinion of course :)

I have some tattoos on my arms. I haven't seen a policy for or against tattoos at the tech companies I've worked for. I'm in software engineering and people generally do not care about tattoos.

But there is still unconscious or conscious bias against tattoos. I would not be surprised if you have tattoos that cannot be covered up (e.g. on your face or hands) that you'll have trouble with getting external facing roles or roles in management. Then there's the actual tattoos. Are you sporting obscene words, graphic or pornographic images? Those could all ding you too.

For instance, one of our Directors of Product is covered in tattoos up and down his arms, but he could cover up with a long sleeved shirt. Your mileage may vary.